# Yii Relation Modify Value

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two tables, `accounts` and `box`. I need to link the `id` field of `accounts` to the `uid` field of `box`. This is normally simple enough but the field `uid` has a prefix. I am not able to change the Database design and unfortunately stuck with what I have.

If for example I have the Account with `id` of `1`, the field in box will be `uid = prefix_1`. The prefix is always the same and is always separated by an underscore.

I have the following currently.

```
'rl_account'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Accounts', '', 'foreignKey' => array(),'condition'=>'accounts.id = substring(column_name, instr(box.uid, "_") + 1)'),
```

I am unable to manipulate the `uid` value, as I keep getting the error:

```
Unknown column 'accounts.id' in 'where clause'
```

Or I get the error:

```
Unknown column 'uid' in 'where clause'
```

If I change `accounts.id` to `id`. Does anyone know how I could achieve this using the relation or will I need to create a new method for this? For example

```
$data->rl_account()->id
```

If there were some way I could alter `uid` I am sure I could make it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to the issue, albeit not in one line, but as close to as possible. I am not sure if this is possible without using the method I have chosen or another similar method as no searches resulted in an answer and I do not see many people trying to do the same.

My solution is as follows. Create a public variable at the top of the model:

```
public $noPrefix;
```

In after find, I call a method that strips the prefix and leaves me with the id as necessary.

```
public function afterfind()
{
    $this->oldRecord=clone $this;
    $this->noPrefix= self::model()->stripUid($this->uid);
    parent::afterFind();
}
```

I now have a new property of the model with the id I need. I can now create the relation in the standard way.

```
'rl_account'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Accounts', 'noPrefix'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
'rl_account'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Accounts', '', 'on' => 'box.uid = CONCAT("prefix_", accounts.id)'),
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response, unfortunately this has not worked. It seems I cannot acccess uid, if I could access this I could change the value.

Comment: What is the error now? Can you see the complete sql query?